# Why is my Static Image map not working in OpenLayers 6.3.1?

Tags: openlayers

I am trying to build the Static Image map in OpenLayers 6.3.1 directly from [the example](https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/static-image.html?q=static) they provide. It will not work. The console is giving an error of, "Uncaught ReferenceError: Projection is not defined."

The line it is referring to is the instantiation of the projection object.

```
var projection = new Projection({
  code: 'xkcd-image',
  units: 'pixels',
  extent: extent
});
```

I have made a [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sojourner7/ew6cpmru/2/) with my code. Can anyone offer any insight as to why it is not working?

Answer (score 0):

You can refer to the OL build directly by using the full class name, as it is done in the [quickstart](https://openlayers.org/en/latest/doc/quickstart.html) doc,

```
 new ol.proj.Projection
```

The example is using the recommended approach that `import` the required modules and output a custom OL build. You can read more [here](https://openlayers.org/en/latest/doc/tutorials/bundle.html).

The example page has `import Projection from 'ol/proj/Projection';` at the top, which gives access to the projection module. In your jsfiddle, this import statement is not there so you can't refer to `Projection` directly, but rather to the available `ol.proj.Projection`

Comment: I have changed the class notation as you have suggested and it is still not working. Is it possible to use Open Layers version 6 without using the import method? Here is the updated [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sojourner7/hu9qngjd/15/).